# How to Show Alert Message After All Records Inserted to Database

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am working on a Asp.net Project.
I am trying to insert all gridview records to database using jquery ajax. Here is my Code

```
function Insert() {
        var Grid = document.getElementById('<%=gvMyGrid.ClientID%>');
        var Value={};
        for (var i = 1; i < Grid.rows.length; i++) {
            Value.Sr = Grid.rows[i].cells[0].innerText;
            Value.Name = Grid.rows[i].cells[1].innerText;
            Value.Marks = Grid.rows[i].cells[2].children[0].value;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/Insert",
                data: '{Value:' + JSON.stringify(Value) + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                }
            });
        }
        alert('Saved Successfully');
    }
```

It's working fine but I want that it display alert message ('Saved successfully') after all rows insert successfully.

But the problem is when there are many rows it display the alert message before inserting all rows.

Please help......

Comment: On a side note: You'd probably be better off calling the Insert service only once. Save all the Value's in an array and pass them all to the Insert function once instead, and you won't have to bother counting the number of successful inserts on the client side.

Comment: Yes this is the better idea I guess. But I don't know how to send array from .ajax call and receive it in a database in server side.
Please can you help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Insert() {
    var Grid = document.getElementById('<%=gvMyGrid.ClientID%>');
    var Value={};
var count=0;
    for (var i = 1; i < Grid.rows.length; i++) {
        Value.Sr = Grid.rows[i].cells[0].innerText;
        Value.Name = Grid.rows[i].cells[1].innerText;
        Value.Marks = Grid.rows[i].cells[2].children[0].value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/Insert",
            data: '{Value:' + JSON.stringify(Value) + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                count=count+1;       
            }
        });
    }
if(count==Grid.rows.length)
 {
    alert('Saved Successfully');
 }
}
```

Comment: I do not want to down vote, but do note: If the Insert method has any bit of lag, you may very well perform the check "if (count == Grid.rows.length)" before all of the asynchronous ajax calls have completed. In that case, you will not see the success message even if no errors occur.

Answer (score 0):

Use the success: callback to determine when an insert is completed.

Increment a counter variable each time the success callback is called, and when the counter equals "Grid.rows.length", show the success message.

Comment: Hi @Culme
Thanks for your reply. Actually I tried your Idea but unfortunately it's not working :(

Comment: The way I thought is a mix of the replies from Kaushik and Stefan. Use the "count" variable from Kaushiks example, but evaluate it in the success:callback like in Stefan's anser. Something like this:

success: function (response) {
    count=count+1; 
    if(count == Grid.rows.length){ alert('Success!); }
}

Also remember, if any of the inserts fail, the message won't be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the success callback on the ajax function i jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

In the callback, check that it is the last row, if it is, send success message.

Try this code (not tested).

```
function Insert() {
    var Grid = document.getElementById('<%=gvMyGrid.ClientID%>');
    var Value={};
    for (var i = 1; i < Grid.rows.length; i++) {
        Value.Sr = Grid.rows[i].cells[0].innerText;
        Value.Name = Grid.rows[i].cells[1].innerText;
        Value.Marks = Grid.rows[i].cells[2].children[0].value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/Insert",
            data: '{Value:' + JSON.stringify(Value) + '}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                if (i == Grid.rows.length-1) {
                    alert('Saved Successfully');
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I @Stefan
Thanks for your reply. I have tried your Idea but unfortunately it's not working. I put a alert(i) in success: but I found that value of i is not in a row. it shows the value of i like this 1,  4,  7, 2,  12, 22

Comment: Of course it don't work. Sorry!
Change the if condition to:

if (i == Grid.rows.length-1) {

You'll have to take one frem the length, because it's and link.
And the order of the indicies is not important with this code :)

Comment: I've updated the answer with the code change - check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

try this because ajax call is asynchronous he doesn`t wait for response it will execute next statement directly  so use XMLHttpRequest for synchronous connection

```
function doPostAjax(requestURL,formData,callback){
      var xmlhttp;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
      else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                var jText = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                callback(jText);
            }else if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status!=200){
                 handleError(xmlhttp.status);
                 disableAjaxLoadingImageDiv();
            }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("POST",requestURL,true);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
      xmlhttp.send(formData);       
}
```

Comment: Hi @Vishnu Katpure
Thanks for your reply. Can you answer the same code in my case ?

Answer (score 0):

[Shaiwal Tripathi](/users/2732676/shaiwal-tripathi) check this as per your requirement

```
function Insert() {
    var Grid = document.getElementById('<%=gvMyGrid.ClientID%>');
    var Value={};
    var xmlhttp;
    for (var i = 1; i < Grid.rows.length; i++) {
        Value.Sr = Grid.rows[i].cells[0].innerText;
        Value.Name = Grid.rows[i].cells[1].innerText;
        Value.Marks = Grid.rows[i].cells[2].children[0].value;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                //every Success message
            }else if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status!=200){
                 //anyone record false
            }
      }
      xmlhttp.open("POST",requestURL,true);
      xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
      xmlhttp.send('{Value:' + JSON.stringify(Value) + '}');
    }
    alert('Saved Successfully');
}
```